# Building Project in xCode collapses all groups in Project Navigator

Tags: xcode, project-navigator

This is something I have never seen before. I am running **xCode 7.2.1** (cannot update to 7.3 yet) and

> Every time I build my project or build/run my project all my groups in
>   my Project Navigator collapse automatically.

Very frustrating and is really slowing down coding speed. Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or know how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly  appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just check if you have searched anything at bottom, it happens to me sometimes, else please post the screenshot

Comment: I have not searched anything at the bottom - screenshots have been added - I think the issue is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

Step.1 Close Xcode IDE

Step.2 go to your project folder

Step.3 right click on `your_project_name.xcodeproj` file

**show package content**

[image]

Step.4 delete **xcuserdata folder** (*please have backup for safer side*)

Step.5 now open project with Xcode, Clean and Build the project.

This helps me!! please let me know if find any trouble in this.

Comment: Tried what you said - same problem persists.

Comment: any other thoughts on this. Tried everything and it's really slowing me down. Keep in mind it is project-specific. Other projects do not do this

Answer (score 0):

check your behaviours in Xcode preferences, someone might be messing with you and changed your build behaviours! haha

Comment: I checked that initially - everything checks out. My gut is telling me it has something to do with Version Control

Comment: I think you are right, this seems to be the problem - https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/5142

Comment: sadly I don't have a solution to that!